# Why has the <title>-tag to be placed into the <head> element?

Tags: php, html, include, title, head

In the specific example, I got a website that is including many different content pages. Depending on the currently included page, the title is a different one. To achieve this, I got the following dynamic `<title>` **almost at the end of the document**.

```
<title><?php echo $title1,' - ',$title2 ?> - *and some static text here*</title>
```

`$title2` is always in the directly included file and `$title1` is even deeper.

So far I didn't notice any kind of disadvantages. All titles are shown properly and all search results on several search engines seem to accept this method and display it correctly.

Several sites like [W3](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.4.2) say that the `<title>` **must** be in the `<head>` though ... but there's no reason given.

So, what kind of disadvantages do I have due to this?

- Do search engines rank the site badly for that?
- Will old browser versions simply not display the title at all?
- Or is this information just old and it doesn't make a difference these days?

Comment: The disadvantage is that your site surely has a poor architecture if you can't even put the `title` in the correct place.

Comment: Just because I am trying to shorten up several parts of my document, doesn't mean that the whole architecture is poor. I call it experimenting ;) I *can* change it back to how it is supposed to be - that just means a few lines of code more than the current solution in the question above.

Comment: If current browsers let you get away with this, you probably can keep doing it... It just sounds awful, though. Imagine if you have a massive document (for example the [single page HTML5 spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/)), and the user is on a slower connection, they will only be able to see the page title when the entire page has loaded. Nobody cares if you save a few lines of PHP, do things the right way instead. There's a reason why the title of a book is on the front cover...

Answer (score 1):

*Do search engines rank the site badly for that?* and *"Will old browser versions simply not display the title at all?"*

Maybe, or new ones will. The thing, is, you can never no. You do something that is not standard, so for all you know, Google might decide to not index your title at all starting tomorrow, and 'suddenly' nobody can find your site anymore.

*Or is this information just old and it doesn't make a difference these days?*

Yes and no. The information you linked to is about the HTML 4.01 standard, which is indeed old, but that information is still valid for HTML5.

You don't have to have a HEAD tag by the way. The shortest valid HTML5 document with a title would be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Title</title>
```

But still, a TITLE after a BODY is still not valid. Even though you can omit the HEAD tag, it is implied when you start a TITLE tag. And the HEAD tag has to be the first tag inside the HTML tag. A title at the end implies a head at the end, which makes your document invalid.

See: [W3: The head element (html5)](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-head-element)

And when in doubt, you can also check the [W3 validator](https://validator.w3.org/). It will tell you that that minimal document I posted above is valid, but it will be invalid as soon as you start a BODY tag above the title, regardless if and where you end it.

Comment: "The information you linked to is about the HTML 4.1 standard, which is indeed old. In HTML5 you can omit the HEAD tags and even the HTML tags." — 4.01, not 4.1 … and the start and end tags for the head and html elements were optional in HTML 4.x too (and all other versions of HTML for that matter).

Comment: A bit sloppy there. `head` was only required in XHTML. I've updated that paragraph (without mentioning XHTML to prevent further confusion). Thanks!

Comment: *I don't see a reason why that couldn't be at the end of the document, [...]*

That's exactly what I was thinking. Thanks for your opinion and the explanation. If you read anything new regarding this topic, feel free to update - I'll check from time to time.
I would upvote you, I just am not allowed to ^^'